# bind subdomain zone file to keep traffic local

Tags: bind, dns-zone

We have a local owncloud server and if we set up the clients to use the IP everything works fast.  If we setup the domain (a DYDNS subdomain, prsc.noip.me) is VERY slow. A bit of research indicated this is because using prsc.noip.me the traffic goes onto the internet and back. More research indicated the way to get around this was to use a local DNS and use it to resolve the prsc.noip.me to the local IP, rather than the DyDNS service IP.

So I setup a bind9 server and got everything working (including reverse dns).  Bit more research indicated I should setup a zone for the subdomain but cant get this working.   So what I have is

named.conf.local

```
zone "prsc.localhost" {
             type master;
             file "/etc/bind/db.prsc.localhost";
        };

zone "prsc.noip.me" {
             type master;
             file "/ect/bind/db.prsc.noip.me";
        };

zone "0.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        notify no;
        file "/etc/bind/db.192";
};
```

db.prsc.localhost

```
$TTL            604800
@               IN      SOA     pluto.prsc.localhost. pi.localhost. (
                                      2         ; Serial
                                 604800         ; Refresh
                                  86400         ; Retry
                                2419200         ; Expire
                                 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@               IN      NS      pluto.prsc.localhost.
@               IN      A       127.0.0.1
@               IN      AAAA    ::1

; Beow are the A record addresses

router          IN      A       192.168.0.1
pluto           IN      A       192.168.0.5

; Below are the CNAME record addresses (aliuses) - point ot the A records

server01        IN      CNAME   pluto.prsc.localhost
router01        IN      CNAME   router.prsc.localhost.
```

db.prsc.noip.me

```
$TTL            604800
@               IN      SOA     pluto.prsc.localhost. pi.localhost. (
                                      2         ; Serial
                                 604800         ; Refresh
                                  86400         ; Retry
                                2419200         ; Expire
                                 604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@               IN      NS      pluto.prsc.localhost.
@               IN      A       127.0.0.1
@               IN      AAAA    ::1

; Beow are the A record addresses

prsc                    IN      A       192.168.0.50

; Below are the CNAME record addresses (aliuses) - point ot the A records

server01        IN      CNAME   prsc.noip.me.
```

I also have a zone for reverse DNS on the prsc.localhost.  When I start bind I get no errors in syslog.   I can ping pluto, router and google.com so things seem to be working but ping prsc.noip.com returns an unknown host error.

so what am I doing wrong?

Regards,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have setup only 1 A record for prsc.noip.me, and it's prsc.prsc.noip.me. you need an @ IN A 192.168.0.50 (root record)

Comment: Sorry, I kind of follow bit be ace if you cold tell me what lines I need to change to what.

Comment: OK so I tried changing

    'prsc                   IN      A       192.168.0.5'

to

    '@                       IN      A       192.168.0.5'

But still no joy

Comment: Did you bounce BIND?

Comment: Yes, and tried it also without the CMAME record also.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I gave up on bind9 and used dnsmasq.  Much easier to setup, lightweight and perfect for what I want to do.